# Why does i.e mean that is?

Tags: ambiguity

I learned  that i.e means :

> that is or in other words

but how does this make sense? shouldn't it be: t.i in this case?

Comment: This is very easy to google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Latin, not English.

See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(I)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_%28I%29) where you can see that it's short for "id est".

By the way, the proper way to write abbreviations is with periods after each letter, i.e. "i.e.".

Comment: OK. Please note that there should be a period after each letter (see my edit.)

Comment: +1 and *id est* is Latin for *that is*.

Answer (score 0):

The letters "i.e." are an abbreviation of the Latin phrase *id est*, which can be directly translated as "that is." The alternative translation, "in other words," is offered as a more colloquial phrase.

Comment: I’m afraid you’ve gotten your [ibids](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ibidem) mixed up with your [ids](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/is#Pronoun).